Failed to Write Nullable Group to Fixed Length File using BeanIO
I'm trying to write a fixed-length file using BeanIO. I want to print totalHeader, totalTrailer, totalEnd only if subSuite is set to null. However, an exception occurred when I attempted this.
@Group
class File {
    @Record
    lateinit var totalHeader: TotalHeader

    @Group(minOccurs = 0)
    var subSuite: SubSuite? = null

    @Record
    lateinit var totalTrailer: TotalTrailer

    @Record
    lateinit var totalEnd: TotalEnd
}

@Group
class SubSuite {
    @Record
    lateinit var header: SubHeader

    @Record
    var details: List<Detail> = emptyList()

    @Record
    lateinit var trailer: SubTrailer
}

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.Collection (java.lang.String and java.util.Collection are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.RecordCollection.getCollection(RecordCollection.java:113)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.RecordCollection.marshal(RecordCollection.java:63)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.Group.marshal(Group.java:64)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.Group.marshal(Group.java:64)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.BeanWriterImpl.write(BeanWriterImpl.java:90)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.BeanWriterImpl.write(BeanWriterImpl.java:52)

How do I solve this problem?
